# Proper procedure for programatically revoking celery tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I wrote a small Python script for revoking celery tasks:

```
from mydjangoproj.celery import app
i = app.control.inspect()
active = i.active(safe=True)
reserved = i.reserved(safe=True)
# Get the uuids for the active and reserved tasks
revoke_ids_list_a = [task['id'] for (worker, tasks) in active_filtered.iteritems() for task in tasks]
revoke_ids_list_r = [task['id'] for (worker, tasks) in reserved_filtered.iteritems() for task in tasks]
# combine them into one big list
revoke_ids_list = revoke_ids_list_a + revoke_ids_list_r
# Perform the revoking
revoked = []
for tid in revoke_ids_list:
    app.control.revoke(tid, terminate=True)
    revoked.append(tid)
```

It seems that this *sort of* works. Nevertheless there are often some tasks left over that don't get revoked, and I also seem to occasionally need to run the script multiple times to kill everything.

Is there something I'm missing? (I know that stopping the daemon and issuing `celery -A mydjangoproj purge -f` would do it, but I don't want to purge for various reasons)

The other problem is that after restarting the celery daemon and beat, some of the tasks that I believed to have been revoked start running again in the worker. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It's depends from backend you using on your project, revoke() working only with AMQP and Redis brokers.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#remote-control

> Note that remote control commands must be working for revokes to work.
>   Remote control commands are only supported by the RabbitMQ (amqp) and
>   Redis at this point.